# Как сделать программу под stm32f103

Tags: c, arduino, stm32

Есть плата stm32f103 с стандартным 4pin SWD интерфейсом и программатор st-link v2. Среда - win7 x64.

Перечитав несколько статей на хабре и кучу всяких формумов, не получается собрать программу для stm32f103. Даже сложно понять какую среду лучше использовать.

Я уже скачал android студию (arduino genuino от arduino.cc), студия собирает какой-то бинарник незнаю для чего, поскольку в выборе нет stm32, надо собирать под android genunio uno (инструменты плата)? Или под что-то другое? Или платформу нужно импортировать?

Пакет arm-none-eabi-* тоже скачал. На хабре (плата и прошивальщик как на картинках хабра по ссылке далее) http://habr.com/ru/post/354670/ вижу пример для ассемблера, а как на `с` собрать?..

Прошивальщик плату увидел, прошить можно.

```
12:30:42 : ST-LINK Firmware version : V2J34S7
12:30:42 : Connected via SWD.
12:30:42 : SWD Frequency = 4,0 MHz.
12:30:42 : Connection mode : Normal.
12:30:42 : Debug in Low Power mode enabled.
12:30:43 : Device ID:0x410 
12:30:43 : Device flash Size : 128KBytes
12:30:43 : Device family :STM32F10xx Medium-density
```

Андроид студия плату не видит, меню порт - недоступно, какой программатор выбирать - не понятно. st-link поддерживает студия или нет - не понятно.

Для начала вопрос - как собрать бинарник. И если не сложно - какую среду можно задействовать бесплатную.. (т.к. на формумах ссылки часто битые).

UDP
Бинарник собрать получилось через EmStudio, прошил, начал дебаг, дебаггер дошёл до 
`bl  SystemInit` А на `SystemInit` на самой первой ассемблерной команде (то ли enter то ли что-то такое) - виснет при входе в процедуру, что очень удивило. Буду пробовать другие среды. Может что напутал.

CubeMX и SW4. Установить получилось, CubeMX - просто конструктор. SW4 - не видит stlinkv2. Дебага нет (он вроде есть но не понятно почему не работает), минимальную программу для проверки пока что не составил - соответственно оценить SW4 не могу. Но то что нет дебага - в минус.

Планирую сделать сокращенную небольшую клавиатуру (84-90 клавишную) с совмещенной раскладкой, так что USB-HID ещё прийдется много почитать. USB - добавляет сложности.

Comment: Да, по большому счёту нужна среда разработки. CubeMX  - знакомое название, попробую погуглить установить... +  STM Workbench это надо поверх CubeMX  ставить?

Comment: Не получается быстро поставить, а через arm-none-eabi-сс собрать бинарник - сильно сложно?

Comment: Если нужна помощь в лайв режиме - можете добавить меня в телеграмм @Teivaz

Comment: Спасибо, я подготовлюсь, скачаю среды, если соовсем никак - то пожалуй задам. МК stm32 уже отпразновал своё 10-летие, но всё же информация как под него писать - разнится.

Comment: @Teivaz если stlink не видит чип, то считать что чип сгорел? Я купил stm32l151 питание 3v3 ток 8uA, небольшой скачёк при старте запаяв в переходник 48pin, кварц один, пробовал 8МНz-smd новый 20MНz-выпаяный с старой видяхи, если способ определить живой чип или нет? Уже думаю выпаять конденсаторы при кварце... Програматор должен увидеть чип без кварца или ещё как? (питаю от программатора, кондеры по питанию кварц с двумя кондерами и все)

Comment: @nick_n_a у меня бывало на переходнике что программатор не видит чип, но как только я подключаю к пинам логический анализатор, то чип начинает распознаваться. Я искал данные по нагрузке и сопротивлению, схемы согласования но ничего такого производитель не даёт. Так что можно попробовать подключить какой-то прибор и попробовать прошить. Ну и скорость ставить самую низкую

Answer (score 1):

STM32 CubeMX: https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html

STM32 Workbench: https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/sw4stm32.html

Обе программы бесплатно, требуется только login.

CubeMX: Запускаете, выбираете вашу плату. Он скачивает все небходимое для вашей платы (firmware package, включая примеры). Делаете конфигурацию (pinout и т.д.). Генерируете код в формате STM32 Workbench.

Открываете проект в STM32 Workbench. Build + Run.

Примеры: запускаете STM32 Workbench. Открываете один из примеров, скачанных с помощью CubeMX (CubeMX Repository). Build + Run.

Comment: Установил CubeMX, поставил галочку в USB (галочка Device (FS) может для работы usb она не нужна? Но другой нету...) и... получил восклицательный знак на TIM1. На плате два кварца (32khz часовой и 8 Mhz), и что хочет таймер... Как его настроить... пока буду гуглить. Ссылок для начинающих нет случайно?

Comment: Удалось таки скачать http://www.ac6-tools.com/downloads/SW4STM32/

Comment: SW4 - это екслипс, он при старте (Меню Run-Run) не видит stlink, где его пнуть что б он увидел stlink? Или он коннектится с программой на чипе не через stlink? Пишет OpenOCD Unplugged target or STLink already use or STLink USB driver not installed. (понятно что из утилиты STLink проверил что чип есть, нажал Disconnect и закрыл окно)

Answer (score 1):

По сути писать программу и компилировать можно вручную. Среды разработки только лишь помогают это делать.

В этом процессе есть несколько основных шагов:

1. Установка тулчейна. Здесь всё довольно просто - ARM предоставляет свой gcc тулчейн `arm-none-eabi`.
2. Описание памяти. Здесь нужно иметь линкер скрипт (.ld файл) Он генерируется IDE, или пишется вручную по даташиту. Этот файл указывает линковщику какие области памяти можно использовать для кода и данных.
3. Настройка билд системы. Я рекомендую использовать CMake поскольку процесс там довольно простой, но при желании можно использовать и просто make.

Вот ссылка на простой пример того как можно скомпилировать проект для микроконтроллера используя CMake https://github.com/Teivaz/cmake-stm32

В своем проекте я использую Visual Studio Code с плагином [cortex-debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marus25.cortex-debug) подключенным через openocd для отладки.

Я подробно описал этот процесс в своей статье [The Microcontroller and How to Program It Without an IDE](https://teivaz.com/the-microcontroller-and-how-to-program-it-without-an-ide/).

---

Следующим шагом будет настройка рантайма си. Там нужно сделать три дополнительных шага - инициализация `bss` сектора нулями, инициализация `data` секции и вызов функции `__libc_init_array()`. Пример можно посмотреть здесь:
https://github.com/Teivaz/zeppelin/blob/master/Modules/Nest/src/boot.c#L9-L52

Затем подключение CMSIS и HAL библиотек. Их можно взять прямо из Cube IDE. Кроме того, CubeMX очень хороший конфигуратор для микроконтроллеров рекомендую использовать его, а потом адаптировать сгенерированный код для вашего проекта.

Comment: У вас описан МК stm32 серии 3xx, у меня 1xx, какие отличия будут, опции компилятора/линкера будут те же, отличия будут - только файлы stmxxxxx.ld и stmxxxx.svd? На что обратить внимание?

Comment: @nick_n_a В линкер файле будет отличаться только размер памяти. Хочу обратить внимание также не тот факт, что это базовый сетап и там нет нормальной инициализации си рантайма. SVD файл нужен только для визуализации регистров при отладки и его можно просто скопировать из IDE

Comment: @nick_n_a я отредактировал ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Для общего развития... arm-none-eabi - оно собирает программы к нескольким видам мк, именно опция -mcpu=cortex-m0plus - выбирает линейку stm32? Т.е. тут переключаются виды процессоров (т.е. система команд, там можно выбрать грубо говоря stm32 или atmel или другой который поддерживает arm-none-eabi)?

Comment: @nick_n_a именно так. Ещё нужно смотреть есть ли у процессора поддержка чисел с плавающей точкой, но как правило у простеньких контроллеров её нет, так что нужно выставлять программную поддержку  `-mfloat-abi=soft `

Comment: Может ли программа виснуть при входе в SystemInit? Сделалось цикл copy, чистка BSS, потом `bl SystemInit` а потом... На первой же ассемблерной инструкции как бы её выполняет но стоит на месте. Что можно посмотреть если это случилось? Делаю шаг, а регистр PC без изменений, и в SystemInit тупо на верху в дебаге висит. Или эта зона запрещена для дебага?

Comment: @nick_n_a, был не так давно доклад на конференции про baremetal https://youtu.be/Yv4nMocX78Q

Comment: @nick_n_a подобное может произойти когда вектор прерываний настроен неправильно или не полностью. Или произошло событие и процессор попал в обработчик и завис в цикле. Попробуйте нажать на паузу когда такое происходит - возможно он в обработчике.